# Toggle a boolean field in all mongodb subdocuments

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a document with some subdocument where each subdocument has a boolean field.

```
{
    title: String
    children: [{
        exit: Boolean,
        doc: String
    }]
}
```

Is there a simple way to make one db call to toggle all the boolean of all the documents for all the subdocuments?

As far as i can see, I can do ..

```
Model.find()
.then(function(items) {
    // manipulate item.children and toggle the exit field.
    // and save them one by one
})
```

But is there a simpler method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you wish to update multiple array inside one document, it is always better to query it once, bring it to server, mutate everything then save it again to replace the single old document

```
Model.find()
.then(function(items) {
    // manipulate item.children and toggle the exit field.
    var newChildren = items.childrens.map(x => x.exit = false)

    //replace the old children 
    items.children = newChildren

    items.save(); // no this is not saving one by one. this command save this item once, including all of it's children
})
```

Comment: OK thats what i did. I figure i had to do that.

Comment: great intuition :)

Comment: I was really looking for some ways to save all the parent documents "atomically" - via a single mongodb call. I guess i can't.